# bluetooth le works 8.4.1 but slow ios 9

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I have an app that connects to an adafruit bluefruit micro(arduino), to control a servo.

The app uses a slider to send a value to move the servo.

The app works correctly on an ipad mini running ios 8.4.1., but on an iphone 6s running ios 9.1 the data is not sent to the device immediately, there is a pause after i move the slider then the servo moves.

I've tried moving the code the slider calls onto a separate thread but still there is a delay.

I know that the 6S can send the data fast enough because I've tested it with the adafruit bluetooth connect LE app(even downloaded the source code from git hub and run that), that app has an option to send gyro information to the adafruit micro - which it does in real time.(by checking arduino serial monitor)

(What's strange is that I added the slider to the source code from adafruit git hub and though all the gyro data etc is sent fast enough the slider data is sent with a delay.)

The app seems to think that it is sending data - I've added various print statement to the code so I can see what the app is doing. Including a print statement just before the CBPeripheral write Value method, and I added an extension to the CBPeripheral that takes the exact same variables as the writeValue method but prints them out to console, which I call immediately after the writeValue call.

My question is what changes have occurred in ios 9 that might account for the delay.

Thanks